# GKE creating ingress error - "Error during sync: error running backend syncing routine: error ensuring health check ...[redacted]"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Installed Prometheus & Grafana from the marketplace. Wanted to make Grafana externally accessible.

Created the following Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-service
  namespace: prometheus-grafana
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'

spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  sessionAffinity: None
  selector:
    k8s-app: grafana
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
```

Next, created the Ingress, looking like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress

metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-sample-app"
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: prometheus-grafana

spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: grafana-service
    servicePort: 80
```

After applying the Ingress (with `kubectl apply`) I went to the ingress details view in GKE web UI see the progress of creating it and that's where the error message says:

```
Error during sync: error running backend syncing routine: error ensuring health check: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.timeoutSec': '30'. TimeoutSec should be less than checkIntervalSec., invalid
```

What did I do wrong and how to fix it? Is there any better, more correct way to make Grafana publicly accessible?

Comment: If you used them from Google market place you would already get a url as it already generates the service for you or did you use someother way to deploy ?

Comment: @tarunkhosla Just from the marketplace. The service that automatically gets generated is of type ClusterIP which is seemingly not suitable to target by the ingress. When I try to target the existing service, I get the error: `error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "prometheus-grafana/prometheus-1-grafana" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"`

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/k8s/prometheus#expose-the-grafana-service-externally 

Try from here , it explains how to expose it.

Comment: @tarunkhosla That indeed seems to be the correct way and it works, thank you! I somehow missed that part from the documentation. You may make it an official answer. Although the reason of the original error message remains a mystery then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official document [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/tree/master/k8s/prometheus#expose-the-grafana-service-externally) suggests correct way to expose Google Prometheus Grafana Service from Market place.